# removeClass('data-element="xxx"'); not working

Tags: jquery

I have html code like this:

```
<div class="smt" data-smt="41" data-element="do">
```

how I can remove this special attribute [data-element]? I trying like this, but not working:

```
removeClass('data-element="do"');
removeClass('[data-element="do"]');
removeClass('[data-element]="do"');
```

I suspect a syntax error, am I right? it should be simple, but my strong point is PHP, not JS. Thx for help.

Comment: `data-element=...` isn't a class, it's an attribute with a value. Use `removeAttribute('data-xxx')` or `delete dataset.xxx`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: You added [tag:jquery] which if you use it then you might want to take a look at https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think removeAttribute function may work for you.

```
document.querySelector('[data-element="do"]').removeAttribute('data-element')
```

will remove the attribute data-element.